# All-female anime; One girl is blind, another is an idiot. Includes a ranking system with classes "A" to "F"

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to find this anime that has 5(?) main characters who were all girls. One of them has black hair, one who is super strong (and blind) and another one who is ditzy but is very strong who has either orange or blonde hair.

There was some kind of ranking system with classes A to F.

This show was pretty graphic (some nudity, clothes being ripped apart, etc).

Comment: Was my answer the right one?

Comment: What genre was it? What did the characters do? When did you see it?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be "[Baka and Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baka_and_Test)"? It's not all-female but there are a lot of female characters, sorted into different school classes; with A-Class containing the most able students (some of whom have exceptional strength) and F-Class containing the least able.

There's some "fan-service" (including ripped clothes) but no nudity.

Comment: Er, the video is not available.

Comment: Works fine for me. Try this one instead; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ0_qtBYgMM

Comment: @Richard Thanks; the one in your comment does work for me.

Comment: And now that one is not available.:-D

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I shall continue my multi-year game of whack-a-mole with the publishers.

Comment: :) Linking the trailers is a bit safer FWIW.